# How to manage a JWT login procedure from Micronaut client to a REST API?

Tags: api, authentication, jwt, client, micronaut

I am new to Micronaut and trying to develop a gateway that connects on the client side to a REST API. The API requires an authentication token which is obtained by first sending a POST requests with credentials in the body. The API is then responding with a valid token which needs to be refreshed from time to time. I am able to inject a bearer token in the headers to authenticate my requests but I do not understand whether I have to handle the whole authentification process myself or if the Micronaut framework can manage it on its own?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could create an `HttpClientFilter` to handle authentication, refresh and the header. You can find an example [here](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#clientFilter) which cover basic authentication.

Yours will be more complicated since you need to refresh etc.

Also doing this way, allow you to decouple your authentication code from your API.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
In fact I already have a client filter which injects the token in the outgoing requests.
With your suggestion, does that mean it will post an Auth request each time before sending any get request?

Comment: No, the filter will have to manage the token life cycle, which means, if you don't have a token, you authenticate, if the token is expired or the API tells you the token is expired, you refresh it

Comment: So is there a way I can extract the token from the response and set it as an app configuration parameter?

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you are meaning when you speak of app configuration parameter. Is that the `application.yml` ? Only the credentials should be stored as configuration. The token should be stored in memory, which means if you restart the server, another one will ge generated.

Comment: Yes you're right that's the file. Thanks, your answer makes sense.